# Html list to behave like table with dynamic column width

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap typeahead (angular) with a custom template.
The way the dropdown is generated is that is creates a list (ul/li). I have three values in each li of the list, and I want them to display as a table where the width of the middle column is set to the size of the longest value.

So, the typeahead basically generates a list that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a><span>something</span><span>Some long company name LLC</span><span></span>abc</a></li>
<li><a><span>something</span><span>Some really nice account</span><span>abcde</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>something</span><span>Third Account</span><span>abc</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>something</span><span>Fourth Account</span><span>abc</span></a></li>
```

I have this CSS to make it behave like a table:

```
ul .dropdown-menu {
   display: table;
   table-layout:fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

ul li a {
   display: table-row;
}

ul li a span{
   display: table-cell;
   width: auto;
   padding: 0px 9px 0px 0px;
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]
You can see there are three columns. I want the middle column to be the width as the longest value (Some long company name LLC in this case), so that the values in the far right column are all aligned. How can I do this? I do not want to set a fixed column size because the values come from a database and will vary quite a bit in length.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Determining width based on data content is an impossible task, unless you want to do a very expensive operation of pinging the data and finding the longest string and setting the width on the fly.  Personally, I would set a static width and put in ellipses for any overflows.